# Eclipse Debugger will not show the shared area

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I've had this error before in pydev perspectives in the past, and the only solution I've ever managed was to remove the broken perspective and start a new one.
The problem is this:
Normally the different panes of the workspace can be minimized, maximized, and regular size. Right now, I cannot get the "shared area" code section of the debug perspective to show up at all. I can peak at it while it's minimized, but that's all I can manage.
What's more, eclipse automatically switches to debug, so it's basically impossible for me to debug code right now.
I'd really like to know why this is happening to me, and how to avoid and/or fix it.
Also, I'm currently running java 7, I have not updated yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Window, Reset Perspective which will give you your shared area back, although also obviously reset any other views you may have.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your time and answer. I was so crazy about it :)